# Inserting data into an array - do not show numbers in json_encode

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array `$fields` which is 2D. It's not a standard class and fetched from database. What I need to do is: Insert data into another array and give results like this (JSON encoded):

```
"fields": {
    "0": [{
        "field": "text",
        "name": "link",
        "label": "Link",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
    }, {
        "field": "xx",
        "name": "xx",
        "label": "xx",
        "required": xx,
        "type": "xx"
    }],
    "1": {
        {
            "field": "xx",
            "name": "xx",
            "label": "xx"
        },
        {
            "field": "xx",
            "name": "xx",
            "label": "xx"
        }
    }
}
```

What I get is:

```
"fields": {
    "0": [{
        "field": "xx",
        "name": "xx",
        "label": "xx",
        "required": xx,
        "type": "xx"
    }, {
        "field": "xx",
        "name": "xx",
        "label": "xx",
        "required": true,
        "type": "xx"
    }],
    "1": {
        "2": {
            "field": "xx",
            "name": "xx",
            "label": "xx"
        },
        "3": {
            "field": "xx",
            "name": "xx",
            "label": "xx"
        },
    }
}
```

Now I need to insert data to `$f` array and then `$f` array into array `$r`. To print like this `"1": {` or `"0": {` I use this:

```
$r = array(
    'f' => (object) $f
);
```

The PHP code:

```
foreach($fields AS $c => $field) {
    $f[$field['id']][$c] = array(
        "field" => $field['field'],
        "name" => $field['name'],
        "label" => $field['label'],
    );
    if($field['required'] == "1") {
        $f[$field['id']][$c]['required'] = true;
    }
}
```

The issue mainly is `$c` thing, if I just do `[]` instead of `[$c]`, it makes another array. I use the JSON encoded in JavaScript code and both the JSON encoded result works but I need the first one.

Comment: to me it's not really clear what 1st your input is, 2nd what the desired output is. Could you make that a bit clearer in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first JSON output is invalid. I hope it's just a typo from copying it into the question.

```
"1": {
    {
```

should be `"1": [ {`. 
If that's the case you can simply renumber the arrays after your code:

```
foreach($f as &$ff) $ff = array_values($ff);
unset($ff);
```

Or if you don't know or like references:

```
foreach($f as $key => $ff) $f[$key] = array_values($ff);
```

Then json_encode should create the output you want. (PHP arrays result in JSON arrays if the keys are numeric, start from 0, and have no holes; otherwise they will be encoded as JSON objects)

If you want to avoid another loop you could use:

```
foreach($fields AS $field) {
  $f[$field['id']][] = array(
    "field" => $field['field'],
    "name" => $field['name'],
    "label" => $field['label'],
  );

  //hacky way to get the key of the array just created
  $c = count($f[$field['id']) - 1; 
  if($field['required'] == "1") {
    $f[$field['id']][$c]['required'] = true;
  }
}
```

Or create the array first and insert it in the end (a little cleaner imo):

```
foreach($fields => $field) {
   $tmp = array(
    "field" => $field['field'],
    "name" => $field['name'],
    "label" => $field['label'],
  );
  if($field['required'] == "1") {
    $tmp['required'] = true;
  }
  $f[$field['id']][] = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. It works but it means I have to run loop twice to do that. Isnt there any way to do that directly when we are fetching from $fields and insert data in to $f, that would be really helpful.

Comment: I added two more options that avoid the issue with [] creating two arrays.